# How to delete older files using a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

How to find and delete older files (older than 7 days) in a folder using a bash script? It's a folder in a server which contain automatic backups. Need to delete old ones automatically so there's space for new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@machine "find /path/to/files/ -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;"
```

name the script as **some_file_name.sh** and give execute permissions.

```
 chmod +x file_name.sh
```

Run it as `./file_name.sh` or `bash file_name.sh`

Answer (score 1):

For a short and easy to remember version :-  
                                                `find <directory path> -ctime +7 -delete` 
This will delete files older than 7 days

Answer (score 0):

Using the below command, first confirm the file list:

```
find . -mtime +7
```

If the list is correct, using below the files can be deleted.

```
find . -mtime +7 -exec rm '{}' \;
```